# Conectar yii2 con LDAP de Zimbra?

Tags: yii2, ldap

Estoy intentando conectar yii2 con el LDAP de zimbra utilizando el plugin Adldap2, no obtengo ningun error he probado desde la consola de yii ejecutar yii ldapcmd/import-all-users, se ejecuta el comando sin producirse ningun error pero desde la aplicacion web no puedo hacer login. Este es la configuracion realizada

```
'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
        'ad' => [
            'class' => 'Edvlerblog\Adldap2\Adldap2Wrapper',
            'providers' => [
                'default' => [
                    //Connect this provider on initialization of the LdapWrapper automatically
                    'autoconnect' => true,
                    'config' => [
                      //  'account_prefix' => 'mail=',
                        'account_suffix' => '',
                        'domain_controllers' => ['zimbra.gporellana.gob.ec'],
                        'base_dn' => 'dc=gporellana,dc=gob,dc=ec',
                        'admin_username' => 'uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=zimbra',
                        'admin_password' => 'mypassword',
                    //Enable SSL
                    //'port' => 636,
                    // 'use_ssl' => true,
                    // 'use_tls' => true,
                    ]
                ],
            //another provider
            ]
        ],
```

Estoy utilizando el metodo de autenticacion rbac

Comment: Podrías poner el error que te sale ?

Comment: no me sale ningun error si doy algun valor a account_suffix ahi si me da error C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-starter>yii ldapcmd/import-all-users
Exception 'Adldap\Auth\BindException' with message 'Invalid credentials'

Comment: Sigo intentando la conexion y segun lei tenia que cambiar en el archivo /config/main.php el identity class y he colocado como indica la documentacion lo siguiente 'indentityClass' => 'Edvlerblog\Adldap2\model\UserDbLdap' pero ahora me da error al abrir la aplicacion, si alguien puede ayudarme el error es este:    Setting unknown property: yii\web\User::indentityClass